# Yii tries to autoload native classes

Tags: php, yii

I'm playing around with the Yii framework, and decided to do some file foo with the [`finfo` class in php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php#example-2349), like so:

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
```

This should work without issue (and it works just fine outside of Yii), I don't see why it shouldn't.  However, this isn't the case, Yii attempts to autoload the `finfo` class causing the obvious error:

```
include(finfo.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to beat Yii into submission?

**Edit**: I still haven't figured out why it craps out within Yii, but it does so right after the call to `spl_autoload_register()`, so I don't know.  However, this problem seems to only be available on my Windows based workstation (and not my OSX laptop), and only in the php 5.4 dev server.  When I bother to run Apache, `finfo` works fine within Yii even on Windows...

So, my conclusion is that the built in dev server in php is a bit derpy on Windows.  A shame really, the dev server is really rather practical usually.

Comment: If an autoload is attempted, the class has not yet been declared. You need to load the class file at some point and the autoloader is probably your best bet. If the autoloader fails, you should make sure it has the correct path information available so that it can successfully load your files.

Comment: It's very strange that it works outside of `Yii` and not inside. Perhaps you are trying to do this inside a namespace -- does `new \finfo(...)` work?

Comment: @Jon Negative, I tried escaping it to the global namespace, but it still thinks that it doesn't exist. However, some testing shows that indeed it doesn't seem to exist when I try to call it from within my method.  However, shoving the same `if(class_exist('finfo')) echo 'foo'` says that it does when I stick it on top in the index.php file.